# Read multiple data in block method IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimage

I am trying to download a series of images from the database in this way:

```
- (void)dowloadAdditionalFileDataForFileObjectId:(NSString *)assignedObjectId andUserID:(NSString *)userID completition:(void (^) (BOOL success))block {
if (userID != nil && assignedObjectId != nil) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AdditionalFileData"];
    [query whereKey:@"fileAssignedObjectId" equalTo:assignedObjectId];
    [query whereKey:@"userID" equalTo:userID];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFObject *object = [objects firstObject];

            dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
            dispatch_group_enter(group);

            __block  UIImage *image1;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            if (object[@"image1"] != nil)
                [self downloadDataForObject:object withParameter:@"image1" andCallback:^(NSData *data) {
                    image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    dispatch_group_leave(group);
                }];
            });

            __block  UIImage *image2;
            if (object[@"image2"] != nil)
            [self downloadDataForObject:object withParameter:@"image2" andCallback:^(NSData *data) {
                image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }];

            dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

            [DBManager storeAdditionalDataForFileWithObjectId:assignedObjectId forUserID:userID withImage1:image1 andImage2:image2 andImage3:image3 ...] local:NO completition: ^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished)
                    block(YES);
                else
                    block(NO);
            }];
        }
        else
            block(NO);
    }];
}
else
    block(NO);
}

- (void)downloadDataForObject:(PFObject *)object withParameter:(NSString *)parameter andCallback:(void (^)(NSData *data))callback{
[object[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", parameter]] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    callback(data);
}];
}
```

If I was just to write:

```
image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[... getData]];
```

then everything works fine, however the user interface is blocked until the process is over. 
I want some system such that the data is downloaded in the background. Since I might have more images than 2, nesting the blocks would't solve anything.
 I tried using the code you see above.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention explicitly that all of the download methods such as

> getDataInBackground

call the Parse SDK ([Parse.com](http://www.parse.com)).

Comment: I'm not sure about your method's name, just because its name says `...InBackground`, how can you be certain it is running on a background thread indeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the bolts library for this, which parse already includes. Would make the code a lot simpler, the example below could be easily extended for more than 2 images or other files.

```
    // do your query
    PFObject *object = [objects firstObject];
    PFFile *file1 = object[@"image1"];
    PFFile *file2 = object[@"image2"];
    BFTask* task1 = [file1 getDataInBackground];
    BFTask* task2 = [file2 getDataInBackground];
    [BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:@[task1, task2]] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if(!task.error){
            UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:task1.result];
            UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:task2.result];
            // do your thing with the images
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

Comment: I'm getting the error No known class method for taskForCompletionOfAllTasks even if I have the latest version of parse

Answer (score 2):

Although I think you just need to use the "includeKey" method on a PFQuery, the full query should look something more like (see the includeKey Part):

```
@interface MyParseObject:PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (retain) NSArray *images;
@end

@implementation MyParseObject
@dynamic images;

int completed;

void (^loadingImagesComplete)(BOOL success);
- (void)loadImagesWithItemCompletion:(void(^)(UIImage *relatedImage))imageCompleted andCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success))processCompleted{

    loadingImagesComplete = processCompleted;
    completed = 0;

    PFQuery *queryForItems = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"yourClassName"];
    [queryForItems whereKey:@"yourKey"  equalTo:@"yourValue"];



    //This is the part I THINK YOURE LOOKING FOR
    //THE QUERY IN YOUR QUESTION WOULD INCLUDE
    //**[query includeKey:@"image1"]**;
    //**[query includeKey:@"image2"]**;
    [queryForItems includeKey:@"images"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        for(PFFile *imageFile in self.images){
            if (!imageFile.isDataAvailable){
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    imageCompleted([UIImage imageWithData:data]); //maybe callback to main queue for this
                    completed++;
                    [self checkLoadingCompleted];
                }];
            }else{
                imageCompleted([UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]]);
                completed++;
                [self checkLoadingCompleted];
            }
        }
    });
}

- (void)checkLoadingCompleted{
    if(completed == self.images.count){
        loadingImagesComplete(YES);// the block called here should make reference to MainQueue when updating any UI Elements
    }
}
@end

@implementation SomeOtherClass
- (void)loadImages{
    [self.myParseObject loadImagesWithItemCompletion:^(UIImage *relatedImage) {
        //this will fire every time an image is done downloading
    } andCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        //this will fire after all images are done downloading
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Misc Data** Solution:

If you want you can use Download Manager that replicates a bit of SDWebimages behaviour. Other alternative is AFNetworking which can help you get the files asynchronously in an easier way and they state to have cache. Both of them are available at GitHub.

[Download Manager](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager)
[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

**Only Images** Solution:

You could use a library like SDWebImages to do that. This library basically provides a category for UIImageView with support for remote images coming from the web. All the download is done in background. It also guarantees that you do not keep download the same image over and over again, due to local caching.

[SDWebImage @ GitHub](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: I am not only downloading UIimages but also NSData

Comment: I have changed my answer to include misc type of data

Comment: @nunofemendes I do appreciate your efforts but if you read the code in the question, I am not downloading the data from a URL, I am using Parse SDK methods.

Comment: Oh sorry. After looking at your code, is that code running asynchronously? I see many image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; that are currently blocking the main thread. Seeing your code, you could maybe wrap them around asynchronous calls with a callback or with a notification from NSNotificationCenter when they are done where you can pass through the image already with the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIImage imageWithData:]
```

This will block until completion: it is not an asynchronous operation.

You seem to have gotten yourself into a bit of a mess trying to sort this issue out and your code has become very complicated because of it, which probably isn't helping you much.

If `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is doing what I imagine it to, it will call the completion block as soon as the data is available. Drop the dispatch groups and use the callbacks: have them update state in a shared method and once all data is available (i.e all blocks have fired) call

```
storeAdditionalDataForFileWithObjectId
```

as you *know* the data is available.

Answer (score 1):

Use a great Github library called Superman.

```
#import "Superman.h"
```

And then use the following methods.

```
Superman *downloadImages = [[Superman alloc] init];
[downloadImages setDownloads: @"http://...../image1.png", @"http://...../image2.png", @"http://...../image3.png", @"http://...../image4.png", nil];
```